# How to pass a variable from a function to React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I have a page called [id].js

The page has a function that gets the id of a blog post:

```
function BlogPost() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const blogId = router.query.id
}
```

And it also has a react component, which needs to take the value from this function to fetch data. The variable is in the fetch request URL.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
      post: {},
      isLoaded: false
    };
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/featured_item/${blogId}`)
        .then(postsResponse => postsResponse.json())
        .then((post) => {
          this.setState({
            post,
            isLoaded: true
          })
        })
    }
    render() {
      const { post, isLoaded } = this.state;
      if(isLoaded){
      return (

        <motion.div initial="initial" animate="enter" exit="exit" variants={portfolioVariants}>
          <Posts post={post}/>
        </motion.div>
      )
        }else{
        return(
          <Loader />
        )
        }


    }
  }
```

If i put the actual blog post id, saying '33' at the end of the fetch URL it works fine, but if i put there a variable from the BlogPost() function it says 'blogId is not defined'.

So the question is: how pass this variable into a component?

*UPD*

I did as suggested in the comments, it just gives the same error. Maybe I did something wrong.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
      post: {},
      isLoaded: false,
      id: blogId
    };
    componentDidMount(blogId) {
      fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/featured_item/${this.state.id}`)
```

Comment: do you add the import statement in above code also. If function is in difference file then you need to export it.

Comment: the function is in the same file

Comment: then define it in the class Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useRouter` - is a hook. Your `Home` component - is a class component. You can't use hooks in class components, only in functional. So if you need to get some query parameter from the query string in class component (`id` in your case), you have to wrap your `Home` with `withRouter` HOC:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

... 
export default withRouter(Home);
```

Then you will get access to the router data.

If you use react-router v3, then you could get `id` like this:

```
const {id} = this.props.location.query;
```

If you use react router v4 or v5. You have to install some URL parser like [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) and parse `location` by yourself:

```
import qs from `query-string`;

....

const { id }  = qs.parse(this.props.location.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function variable is not accessible out of function so you need to either use state for getting this data anywhere in the component scope or either store your id in "this" reference like this.id = "your id"

```
BlogPost=()=> {
 const router = useRouter()
 this.setState({id: router.query.id })
}
```

now the fetch url will like this

```
fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wpjson/wp/v2/featured_item/${this.state.id}`)
```

Comment: you cannot pass any argument to componentDidMount().

Comment: I did what you said and added the update at the top, because I can't format the code in the comments. Please please please check it.

Comment: I tried it. Unexpected token, expected "(" (13:17)  Right here:  function BlogPost=()=> {

Comment: remove that function keyword from start of the function.

Comment: but if I make this not an arrow function but a regular js function like function BlogPosts() {}, it gives me the same error "blogId is not defined"

Comment: this function you have "BlogPost" is inside the class or outside the class ?

Comment: This function is outside the class, so it doesn't work(

Comment: So if the function is outside the class then you can get the value of blogId outside of the class using hooks and return that value from function and call that function inside you component.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting blogId from props, please confirm?

In that case:

```
componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/featured_item/${this.props.blogId}`)
        .then(postsResponse => postsResponse.json())
        .then((post) => {
          this.setState({
            post,
            isLoaded: true
          })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Same thing: blogId is not defined((

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `blogId` from the function:

```
function BlogPost() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const blogId = router.query.id
  return blogId
}
```

Then call the function `BlogPost()` in `fetch`:

```
fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/featured_item/${BlogPost()}`)
```

Comment: Can't use hooks in a class component(

Comment: Oh I missed the `useRouter()` part. Then again, you shouldn't be using hooks in the first place, in a class component. The best way for you now is [Andrii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7845022/andrii-golubenko)'s answer.